# Bitnami Redis Cluster Helm Chart unable to bind to persistent volumes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I am doing testing which includes the [Redis Cluster Bitnami Helm Chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis-cluster). However, some recent changes to the chart means that I can no longer set the `persistence` option to `false`. This is highly irritating, as now the cluster is stuck in `pending` status with the failure message "0/5 nodes are available: 5 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind". I assume because it is attempting to fulfill some outstanding PVCs but cannot find a volume. Since this is just for testing and do not need to persist the data to disk, is there a way of disabling this or making a dummy volume? If not, what is the easiest way around this?

Comment: What is PSV? You are using it for testing and don't want to consume the storage, I think you can delete and re-install it when you need.

Comment: Persistent Volume Claim* True, but it looks like the chart by default requires a volume otherwise the pods dont come up

Comment: Yes, you can see this PR: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/pull/9178.

Comment: Yes, ive seen this and i know that persistence is required by default now. My question is how do we set this up now without having an actual service, i.e. some simple method to get it working

Answer (score 1):

As Franxi mentioned in the comments above and provided the PR, there is no way doing a dummy volume. Closest solution for you is to use [emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir)

Note this:

> Depending on your environment, emptyDir volumes are stored on whatever medium that backs the node such as disk or SSD, or network storage. However, if you set the emptyDir.medium field to "Memory", Kubernetes mounts a tmpfs (RAM-backed filesystem) for you instead. While tmpfs is very fast, be aware that unlike disks, tmpfs is cleared on node reboot and any files you write count against your container's memory limit.

Examples:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /cache
      name: cache-volume
  volumes:
  - name: cache-volume
    emptyDir: {}
```

Example with `emptyDir.medium` field:

```
...
 volumes:
  - name: ram-disk
    emptyDir:
      medium: "Memory"
```

You can also to [determine the size limit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/):

> Enable kubelets to determine the size limit for memory-backed volumes (mainly emptyDir volumes).